# Concat categories and subcategories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

There is a table type:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
    (`id` int, `pid` int, `name` varchar(35),
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;

INSERT INTO categories
    (`id`, `pid`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'a1'),
    (2, 0, 'a2'),
    (3, 0, 'a3'),
    (4, 0, 'a4'),
    (5, 0, 'a5'),
    (6, 3, 'a6'),
    (7, 3, 'a7'),
    (8, 5, 'a8'),
    (9, 5, 'a9')
;
```

Where:
**id** - identifier of the category,
**pid** is the identifier of the parent category,
**name** - the name of the category.

How to write a query, to get it like this:

```
|          id |                           path |
|-------------|--------------------------------|
|           1 |                             a1 |
|           2 |                             a2 |
|           3 |                             a3 |
|           4 |                             a4 |
|           5 |                             a5 |
|           6 |                        a3 > a6 |
|           7 |                        a3 > a7 |
|           8 |                        a5 > a8 |
|           9 |                        a5 > a9 |
```

More than one investment can not be.

Comment: what does path contain? `pid + name` or `id + name` ?

Comment: need concat parent_name + child_name

Comment: Desire output from query is bit difficult. It may possible using DB procedure.

Comment: Corrected the description. You can have a stored procedure.

Comment: you have a single subcategory level or the sublevel is variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Refer to Documentation on [JOINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)***

You can use `joins` to get the result.

**Sample**:

```
mysql> SELECT c.id AS child_id
    ->      , c.name AS child_name
    ->      , c.pid AS parent_id
    ->      , p.name AS parent_name
    ->      , IF( c.pid, CONCAT( p.name, ' > ', c.NAME ), c.NAME ) AS path
    ->   FROM categories AS c
    ->   LEFT JOIN categories AS p ON c.pid = p.id
    ->  ORDER BY child_id;
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| child_id | child_name | parent_id | parent_name | path    |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
|        1 | a1         |         0 | NULL        | a1      |
|        2 | a2         |         0 | NULL        | a2      |
|        3 | a3         |         0 | NULL        | a3      |
|        4 | a4         |         0 | NULL        | a4      |
|        5 | a5         |         0 | NULL        | a5      |
|        6 | a6         |         3 | a3          | a3 > a6 |
|        7 | a7         |         3 | a3          | a3 > a7 |
|        8 | a8         |         5 | a5          | a5 > a8 |
|        9 | a9         |         5 | a5          | a5 > a9 |
+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**NOTE**:
Parent - Child tree can be lengthier.
In such cases you better depend on stored procedure or limit the tree to certain levels only.

Answer (score 1):

Sql server:

```
select a.id,
case when b.id is null then concat('a',a.name)
else concat('a',b.name,' > ','a',a.name) end as path
from categories a
left outer join 
(
select id,pid,name from categories
where id in (select pid from categories)) as b
on a.pid=b.id
```

Regards,

Saravanan